# Is it possible to get a boulder from Phobos to one of the poles of Mars?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mars, terraforming, phobos

And what will then be the speed theoretically at which it hits the surface at one of the poles ?

Please, specify your calculations and the trajectory.

Edit: Why should this be a bad question, with such a magnificent answer ?

Comment: not energy, but speed (escape velocity) probably 11.4 m/s or 41 km/h. There is atmosphere on Mars = it will heat up.

Comment: Can you  specify your calculation ?

Comment: How much the stone heats up depends on the shape (more specifically, its air resistance) and weight of the stone. Likewise, energy required to launch the stone depends on weight.

Comment: This looks like a do my home work for me question.

Comment: I do not know much about orbital-mechanics.  But If i don't know where to look for, i can't do my home work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inclination change here is large, close to 90 degrees. For major changes like that, pretty much the only alternative is a [Bi-elliptic transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-elliptic_transfer).

That means the optimal manoeuvre here is to accelerate to Mars escape velocity from Phobos. As the gravity of Phobos can be ignored due to its minuscule size, the required velocity change can be expressed as:

$$\Delta v=\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) \cdot \text{Phobos orbital velocity} \approx 885 m/s$$

Once almost escaped from the Mars system, the spacecraft can do a zero cost "at infinity" burn to change the inclination and fall back towards Mars in a polar orbit intersecting with the atmosphere above the pole. In practice, this manoeuvre costs a few m/s of velocity change as it must be done at a finite distance, but that is a trade off with transfer time.

In total, about $900 m/s \Delta v$ is required.

As for what speed it would hit the poles with, that depends on the trajectory chosen but also the size of the object as the Martian atmosphere can significantly slow down small objects.

[image]

As for why this is more efficient than a more direct trajectory, we can compare it to the simplest approach. That would require us to eliminate all the initial velocity in addition to achieve a polar orbit touching the atmosphere. The total cost of that is $2650 m/s$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your clear description. Please explain to me why throwing the boulder directly towards one of the poles of Mars would not work.

Comment: @Conelisinspace Well it works too, it is just inefficient. A trajectory directly towards the pole has no sideways velocity, and that means we have to get rid of all the original velocity even before starting to accelerate towards the pole.

Comment: Yes, that would be an  enormous waste of energy. But because a boulder    can't do a burn to change the inclination that would mean that it is impossible to get it to one of the poles with the bi-elliptic transfer.

Comment: @Conelisinspace If you want to research this further, I reccomend the [upper Phobos tether](https://hopsblog-hop.blogspot.no/2016/01/upper-phobos-tether.html). It eliminates the need for the large burn.

Comment: @Conelisinspace As for the boulder nature of it, you can attach a rocket to it, and after the small burn make the rocket transfer back to the elliptical orbit before the inclination change and then use aerobraking to get it back to a transfer orbit towards Phobos.